# Angular Material get previously selected value from MatSelectChange event

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am capturing MatSelectChange events from a dynamic forms library in my .ts file. This works just fine, but when I capture the event, I don't know how to acquire the previously selected value.

Getting the current value is easy, I am surprised that the prior value isn't immediately available for access.

The event contains access to `$event.value` and `$event.source`.

I have tried to dig deep into the `source` member, but I can't find the previous value there either as it is just the current select control.

[Link to API](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectChange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get it from the event unfortunately. You will have to store it in a component variable, and read it from there. Which shouldn't add that much overhead, because most of the time you would have to do that anyways:

```
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  selected?: string;

  onChange(event: MatSelectChange): void {
    console.log('Old value', this.selected);
    this.selected = event.value;
    console.log('New value', event.value);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njszdo?file=src/app/select-overview-example.ts)